# Does the "increment" feature in Sequelize scale well?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm investigating the scalibility of [Sequalize](http://sequelizejs.com/) in a production app, specifically the `increment` function, to see how well it can handle when a row could theortically be updated several times simultaneously (say, the totals row of something). My question is can the sequalize `increment` operator be trusted for these little addition operations that could be concurrent?

We're using Postgres on the backend, but I'm not familar with the internals of Postgres and how it would handle this type of scenerio (heroku postgres will be the production host, if it matters).

[The Docs](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/instances#increment) / [The Code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/ec6586578cba930a14c0e40752999819de8a22ff/lib/instance.js#L762-L824)

The sql ran by Sequealize according to the code comments

```
SET column = column + X
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL statements that are run by that framework?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, i did

Comment: @KyleHotchkiss did you ever find out more regarding the concurrency "increment" can handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without complete SQL examples, but I'd say this will likely serialize all transactions that call it on the same object.

If you update an object, the db takes a row update lock that's only released at commit/rollback time. Other updates/deletes block on this lock until the first tx commits or rolls back.